# simple {{ }} not working in angularJS project

Tags: javascript, angularjs

### Issue

---

I am watching a tutorial on AngularJS as it is something that i want to learn more in depth. I have set up a Web Application project in Visual Studio 2015 and created a HTML page inside this project.

I have added the AngularJS nuget package and referenced the angular.js file.

The problem is when i go to do a simple expression to make sure angular is working, it isn't working.

### Code

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
    <body np-app>
        <p>{{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

The expression `{{ 5 + 5 }}` does not display `10`.

Comment: `np-app != ng-app`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `np-app` on your body, this should be `ng-app`.

```
<body ng-app>
    <p>{{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this it will work :**

use `ng-app` instead of `np-app`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="myApp">
        <head>
            <script src="Scripts/angular.js"></script>
            <title></title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
    <body ng-controller="appCtrl">
        <p>{{ 5 + 5 }}</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

**script.js :**

```
var appname = angular.module('myApp', []);
appname.controller('appCtrl',function($scope) {

});
```

Live Demo : http://plnkr.co/edit/I08fbabsLWFkkpfZ9Zog?p=preview